# Inaccessible files in NTFS filesystem, bug or corruption?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I use an external disk for storing media on both Linux and Windows, and it's formatted as NTFS (using ntfs-3g under Linux). I noticed two suspicious files on the filesystem that I can't access or remove:

```
# ls -alhi
ls: cannot access '#batch.txt#': Input/output error
ls: cannot access '.#batch.txt': Input/output error
total 24K
292727 drwxrwxrwx 1 krampus users 4.0K Dec 27 21:08  ./
     5 drwxrwxrwx 1 krampus users 8.0K Dec 22 03:34  ../
     ? -????????? ? ?       ?        ?            ?  .#batch.txt
     ? -????????? ? ?       ?        ?            ? '#batch.txt#'
     [...]
# file -s \#batch.txt\# 
#batch.txt#: cannot open `#batch.txt#' (Input/output error)
# rm -f \#batch.txt\# 
rm: cannot remove '#batch.txt#': Input/output error
```

`batch.txt` was a text file which I presumably edited in emacs some time ago, so this should ostensibly be the autosave file, but clearly something's amiss, and I can't `rm` either file.

This disk is a few years old and probably reaching its end-of-life -- SMART tests come up clean, but I've found reads/writes hanging indefinitely every so often. Could this be caused by filesystem corruption, or have I found an ntfs-3g bug? And in either case, is there anything I can do to remove these files, or should I just ignore it? I've got backups, so I'm just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Kudos for having backups.

Answer (score 2):

Since the essential file attributes like owner, size and timestamp are listed as question marks, this looks very much like some filesystem corruption. You might find more information about the input/output errors in the listing produced by the `dmesg` command.

You might want to run the "check the disk for errors" GUI option or the `chkdsk` command in Windows, since the `ntfsfix` command in Linux ntfs-3g is still somewhat less capable than the native Windows tools.

Comment: “is still somewhat less capable” Wow, that's really an understatement. :D